# loop through array number values

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

the code is breaking at the first if statement. worksheet range error. attempting to loop through myarray. myarray is an array of integers. thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, myarray As Variant

    myarray = Array(122, 123)

    For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
        If Range("O" & i) <> 0 Then
            answer = MsgBox("Price Change. Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
        End If

        If answer = vbNo Then
            Range("F" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ",eac_equipment_list!$P:$S,2,FALSE),"""")"
        End If

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Range("O" & i) = "0"

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `LBound(myArray)` is 0. So `Range("O" & i)` becomes `Range("O" & 0)`, which is not a valid address.

Comment: `Range("O" & myarray(i))`

Comment: urdearboy, thanks for your comment! it works!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to consider:

1. Make sure the `SelectionChange` only involves one cell since your code is not set up to handle multiple cells.
2. You do not need 3 individual `IF` statements. This has been reduced from 3 `IF` statements to 2 (where one makes use of the `ElseIf`)
3. As discussed in comments, `i` just shows the index of your array. If you want the value of the index, you need to use `myarray(i)`
4. Add `Option Explicit` to top of your code. Your variable `answer` needs to be declared

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long, myarray As Variant, answer As Variant

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

myarray = Array(122, 123)

For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    If Range("O" & myarray(i)) <> 0 Then
        answer = MsgBox("Price Change. Are you sure?", vbYesNo)

        If answer = vbNo Then
            Range("F" & myarray(i)).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B" & myarray(i) & ",eac_equipment_list!$P:$S,2,FALSE),"""")"
        ElseIf answer = vbYes Then
            Range("O" & myarray(i)) = 0
        End If

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```